# Why doesn't this regular expression work on python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract some string from a binary file. When I use this regular expression with strings in linux it works fine but it does not work in python.

In **strings**:

```
strings -n 3 mke2fs | grep -E '^([0-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)+)'
```

the result: **1.41.11**

In **python**:

```
import re

f = open("mke2fs","rb").read()
for c in re.finditer('^([0-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)+)',f):
 print c.group(1)
```

The result is empty. How can I resolve this? Is it because of my Python version (I'm using Python 2.7)? I tried using regex (another re alternative) still with no result.

Comment: because `^` is not for each line like in grep.

Comment: `mke2fs` isn't a file - it's a process... So I'm actually surprised you're not actually getting an exception... Look at the subprocess module and capturing output - http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: @JonClements: No, `mke2fs` is a file. It's pretty common to run `strings` against executable. (There may, of course, be zero or more processes whose executable is that file, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: @abarnert Ahh yes - I imagined another pipe in there... my bad

Comment: As a side note, you really should use raw strings (the `r` prefix, as in JBernardo's answer) whenever you use re, or at least whenever you use an re with a backslash in it. Otherwise, you have to remember exactly which characters are and are not backslash escapes in Python strings, which nobody remembers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `re.MULTILINE` flag for `^` to work on your text like grep do.

BTW, it is more readable to use `\d`:

```
for c in re.finditer(r'^(\d+(\.\d+)+)', f, re.MULTILINE):
    print c.group(1)
```

Comment: Great answer. It might be worth mentioning that `grep` and Python `re` are, in general, very different dialects of regex (and, for that matter, `grep -E` is pretty different from `grep`). See http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html for an informal comparison of different dialects. (This particular feature difference is called `(?m)` in the chart, which isn't very useful unless you already know Python/perl/PCRE/something similar…)

Comment: @JBernardo: still no result. But if i remove `^` it does have a result. Like this :
1.0

1.0

2.17

2.15

2.4

2.3

2.2

2.3.4

2.1

2.0

1.41.11

2.2

0.0

Comment: @codesaber Try printing the text first to see if there's anything  there at all.

Comment: @abarnert That's right. Sometimes the language syntax or backward compatibility makes it hard to have an universal regex syntax.